# How to convert a list of dictionaries, within a dictionary, to a list of just values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Essentially I have a dictionary that looks like this.

dictionary = { 'key': [ { 'key': 'value', etc.. } etc...] }

I want a list of just 'value'.  I'm quite new, so how can I go about this? Thanks.

```
    dictionary = {
                   "candles":[
                              { 
                               "open": 78.21,
                               "high": 78.28,
                               "low": 78.12,
                               "close": 78.2,
                               "volume": 16417,
                               "datetime": 1620385200000
                               },
                               {
                                "open": 78.19,
                                "high": 78.26,
                                "low": 78.17,
                                "close": 78.2,
                                "volume": 5928,
                                "datetime": 1620387000000
                                }
                             [
                 }
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output.

Comment: @iota sure, just updated the post

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @iota essentially just the numbers. [78.21, 78.28, 78.12, 78.2, etc...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps :

```
values = []
for key in dictionary:
    for nested_dict in dictionary[key]:
        values += nested_dict.values()
```

`values` will be:

```
[78.21, 78.28, 78.12, 78.2, 16417, 1620385200000, 78.19, 78.26, 78.17, 78.2, 5928, 1620387000000]
```

Comment: Can also do `values.extend(nested_dict.values())` to [extend a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
res = [val for l in dictionary.values() for d in l for val in d.values()]
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Zy3kNK)